# How to do rule-based sorting in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, design-patterns, graph-algorithm

I am trying to plant a garden. Certain plants are good for some plants and bad for others, as in this table:

```
Num Vegetable   Friends       Foes
1   Watermelon  7,4,3          8,6
2   Tomatoes    9,8,6,5,1      7
3   Sunflowers  7,6,11  
4   Zucchini    9,7,3   
5   Eggplant    9,6,2          7,10
6   Cucumbers   9,7,3          8,1
7   Corn        8,6,4,3,1      5,2
8   Cantaloupe  7,4,3          6,1
9   Bell peppers6,5,11,10,2 
10  Swiss chard 2              5
11  Rhubarb     9,3
```

Assuming I have one of each plant and they are being planted in a row, how do I sort them(efficiently) so that I will get the most adjacent friends and no adjacent enemies? There are tools online, but I am trying to understand(the thought process and the implementation).

Comment: I'd start with some sort of back tracking algorithm personally.  But without code this question is off topic.  See the help tab please.

Comment: Where would it be appropriate?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.  [softwareengineering.se] perhaps?

Comment: I assume you're looking for a idea, the way i'd do it is building a graph with the relation of the plants, set the distance between friends to 1, and 100 (some high number) to foes, and use the Dijkstra's algorithm, the shortest way would be what you want